# Select data but allow users and groups to supersede everyone data

Tags: mysql

I have a database which stores simple text expansions. For example, the user enters a `shortcut`, and the `phrase_text` is visible. For the system default shortcuts, the `username` and `group` fields are `null`. If the phrase belongs to a group, then `groupname` will be populated. If it belongs to a user, the `username` field will be populated.

I want a query which will find all the shortcuts for a given user, knowing that if the user has any preferences, they will supersede the group preferences, which in turn supersede the system preferences.

Example data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `phrases2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shortcut` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `groupname` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phrase_text` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 

INSERT INTO `phrases2` (`id`, `shortcut`, `username`, `groupname`, `phrase_text`) VALUES
(1, 'a', NULL,    NULL,     'AAA'),
(3, 'b', NULL,    NULL,     'BBB'),
(4, 'c', NULL,    NULL,     'CCC'),
(5, 'a', 'user1', NULL,     'AAA - for user 1'),
(6, 'a', NULL,    'group1', 'AAA - group1'),
(7, 'a', 'user2', NULL,     'AAA - for user 2'),
(8, 'a', NULL,    'group2', 'AAA - group2');
```

Suppose I want all the phrases for user1. I'd return rows 3,4,5 becuase row 1 is superseded by row 5.

Or, suppose I want all the phrases for user1 who also happens to be in group2. I'd still get rows 3,4,5 because user preference outranks group preference, which outranks system default preference.

Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee6b4f/21

Here is some code that does what I want, but it seems terribly inefficient:

```
set @user='user1';
set @group='group1';

select shortcut, phrase_text from phrases2 where username=@user
union select shortcut, phrase_text from phrases2 where groupname=@group 
    and shortcut not in (select shortcut from phrases2 where username=@user)
union select shortcut, phrase_text from phrases2 where username is null and groupname is null 
    and shortcut not in (select shortcut from phrases2 where username=@user or groupname=@group )
```

Comment: Unclear:  What makes a choice a "preference"?

Comment: So in the data I've shown, there are three shortcuts: A, B and C. For B and C, there are only system defaults, so they are shown. For A, I want to check first to see if there is a user preference (such as lines 5 or 7). If there aren't, then I want to check for a group preference (such as lines 6 and 8). Finally, if there is nothing, then I take the system preference (where groupname and username are both null)

Comment: This may have to be application code, not SQL.